# ComboBox changed before Window is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF / XAML Window that contains a ComboBox that is giving me problems.

The window's ComboBox is firing off the `SelectionChanged` event.
The Debugger callstack shows me that `SelectionChanged` is being called (indirectly) from the Window Constructor.

The problem is that the window has an event `Window_Loaded`, which does some final initialization of data-members.  Because this final initialization isn't done yet, the `SelectionChanged` event fails with a null-reference exception.

There are several ways I could solve this, but I'd like to know the "most correct" way.

- I could fully initialize all my data members in the constructor. This violates the concept of keeping constructors minimal.
- I could code the SelectionChanged event handler to properly deal with some data-members being null.  This is coding to deal with only a startup problem that will never occur once the Window is fully constructed.
- I could make the data-members Lazy-Loaded, so they are not initialized by `Window_Loaded`, but rather when they are first accessed.  Seems like a bit of work to solve a problem that could be solved more simply.

I assume I'm not the first person to deal with UI-events prior to the Window Loaded event.  What is the preferred way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and while tracing through it I had an "a-ha" moment.  I had a default value as "IsSelected", an OnChange event, and a custom loadSettings method.  I blamed the settings method at first, but it turned out that having a default value selected triggered the OnChange event before a handful of the controls were loaded, including the parent combobox which was triggering the null reference.  Once I removed the "IsSelected" and allowed the default value to be null/empty it worked fine and my loadSettings method took care of setting the default or last used value.

Comment: Okay, but that's not an ideal solution. What if you don't want the default to be null?

Comment: @KyleDelaney then your OnChanged handler needs to check if the value has actually changed against your source. If they are equal then ignore.

Answer (score 3):

I usually deal with the (endlessly irritating) SelectionChanged problem like this:

```
bool mySettingSelectionChangedInCode;
private void SetMySettingComboBox(string value)
{
    mySettingSelectionChangedInCode = true;
    mySettingComboBox.SelectedItem = value;
    mySettingSelectionChangedInCode = false;
}
private void mySettingComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (mySettingSelectionChangedInCode)
        return;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most proper way would be to build your application using MVVM pattern. In that case you would not have to deal with those problems. But I realize that it is not always possible to just move to MVVM unless the project is in its very beginning state.

Anyway, the problem you describe I would solve by defining a flag like `IsInitialized` in your window and set it to `true` once you've completed the initialization in the `Loaded` event handler. Then, I would check that flag in the `SelectionChanged` handler and if it is `False` then return from method without doing anything (ignore the call).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
if (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.IsInitialized == true)
{
 //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because you've set the SelectedValue of the combobox after setting the ItemsSource property.